# How to hide white bar from ios target on Haxe(OpenFL)?

Tags: ios, hide, statusbar, haxe, openfl

Please, help to hide white bar on iOS.

In "info.plist" I added:

View controller-based status bar appearance=false;
Status bar is initially hidden=yes;

But it is not helpful.